# Almost everywhere convergence and $L^1$ convergence

Tags: metric-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

In class we have seen how, given the solution for the heat problem (the one done by convoluting with $\frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2 /4t}$), even if the initial condition was only $L^1$, we still had a.e. convergence. For that we introduced some stuff like Hardy-Littlewood maximal function. However, the teacher said that in general if I have a sequence $\{f_n\}$ converging to $f$ in $L^1$ then I can conclude that there is a subsequence converging almost everywhere. Then  he said that there is this general result:

"Given (X,d) a metric space and a succession $\{x_n\}$, then if for every subsequence there is a sub-subsequence converging to a certain $x$, then $x_n \to x$"

But he went on and said we can't conclude that convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence almost everywhere (and there are indeed counterexamples), because "convergence almost everywhere is not induced by any metric". I am not sure about the last quote, but I remember he said there was some problem with the fact that I needed a metric space in order to use the theorem above. Can someone please explain why the theorem above cannot be used in this situtation? I know it must be true, I have counterexamples, but I don't see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer may depend on the measure space $\left(S,\mathcal F,\mu\right)$ we consider. If $S$ and $\mu\left(S\right)$ are finite then almost everywhere convergence is equivalent to convergence in $L^1$.

However, suppose that $\left(S,\mathcal F,\mu\right)$ is such that there exists a sequence $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ which converges in $L^1$ to $0$ but not almost everywhere. 
Suppose that there exists a metric $d$ on the space of  $\mathcal F $-measurable functions such that for each sequence  $\left(g_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$, $g_n\to g$ almost everywhere is equivalent to  $d\left(g_n,g\right)\to 0$. For each subsequence of $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$, due to convergence in $L^1$, you can extract a subsequence which converges almost everywhere to $0$. Using the quoted fact in the opening post, we derive that $d\left(f_n,0\right)\to 0$ hence convergence of $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ almost everywhere to $0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Ok, I see that there cannot be a metric equivalent to the almost convergence. But I don't get why if $S$ and $\mu(S)$ are finite I should have an equivalence. Forgive me, I am not used at all with working with general measures and maybe I got it wrong, but I think that $S=[0,1]$ and $\mu$ the usual Lebesgue measure are examples of what you meant. Now, if I take the succession $\chi_{(0,1)},\chi_{(0,1/2)},\chi_{(1/2,1)},\chi_{(0,1/3)},\chi_{(1/3,2/3)}$ and so on, I still have a succession converging in $L^1$ but not almost everywhere.

Comment: If $S$ and $\mu(S)$ are finite, then $L^1$ is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb R^d$. The case where $S$ is the unit interval with Lebesgue measures falls into the case of the second paragraph of may answer, as your example shows.

Comment: Wait, by finite you mean that the cardinality of $S$ is finite and $\mu$ is some kind of discrete measure over the points of $S$? Sorry but as said I am not used to general measure spaces

Comment: Yes, I meant that $S$ has a finite cardinal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the set of measure zero depends on the subsequence. For every subsequence $\{n_k\}$ there is a set $E(n_k)$ of measure zero such that $f_{n_{k}}(x) \to f(x)$ provided $x  $ is not in this set. The union of these sets of measure 0 need not have measure 0, so you cannot, in general, find one set $A$ of measure zero such that every subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ has  a further subsequence converging to $f$ at every point outside $A$.

Comment: I see that, given the fact that the cardinality of subsequences is $|\mathbb{R}|$, the measure of the union may be not 0. However you showed me there might be a problem, not that there is one. As far as I know, it may be that those sets are all equal and thus the union has still measure 0.